# I want to calculate machine mode time range from this table. How can I write a SQL query for this situation?

Tags: sql, isqlquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MILiE.png)

I could not add image

Comment: 1) Please don't use images for data, use formatted text. 2) You are expected to  show us what you have tried and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Presumably `with data as (select *, lead(time) over (partition by machinename order by time) as nexttime from T) select * from data where machinestate = 'Running'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try do something like this:

```
Select machinestate, 
Lead(machinestate,1) OVER (PARTITION BY machinename ORDER BY time) as 
         next_machinestate, 
Lead(time,1) OVER (PARTITION BY machinename ORDER BY time) - time as 
         time_range 
from your_table
```